# Android API 25 doesn's ask for location permission

Tags: android, react-native

In android manifest I added:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

And I am starting geolocation like:

```
geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        console.log(position);
    }, (error) ...
```

When I run app on IOS it works fine - it asks for location permission.
I am running android 7.1 emulator API 25 and it doesn't ask for permissions?
What am I missing or doing wrong? 
Just to note: android get coordinates on my code so it has permission but it should ask user for that permission first.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the `targetSdkVersion` in **AndroidManifest.xml** to 23 (Android M) or later. That's what worked for me.

Comment: or in `android/app/build.gradle`!

Answer (score 0):

Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

First implement **ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback**

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

if (requestCode == REQUEST_LOCATION) {
     if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
           if ( ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {

           }
     }
}
}
```

Then check if you need a runtime permission

```
if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M ) {
    if ( ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {

        //Location Permission already granted
        map.setMyLocationEnabled( true );
    } else {
        //Request Location Permission
        requestLocationPermission();
    }
}

private void requestLocationPermission() {
        if ( ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission( this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {

            // Should we show an explanation?
            if ( ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale( this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) ) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle("Location Permission Needed")
                        .setMessage("This app needs the Location permission, please accept to use location functionality")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( MainActivity.this, new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION );
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this, new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION );
            }
        }
    }
```

For more about runtime permissions : [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: Yes I understand that. But android on api 25 doesn't ask for permission. It is already grandet when I start app on emulator.